# Compose middlewares in go-chi?

Tags: go, go-http, go-chi

I am writing an API using `go-chi` and my endpoint can be authenticated either via Basic Auth or an API Key. How can I compose two independently functioning middlewares?

Here is what the router looks like:

```golang
router := chi.NewRouter()
router.Use(BasicAuthMiddleware)
router.Use(APIKeyMiddleware)
```

What I really want is to say "If there is a header called `X-API-KEY` then authenticate the endpoint using `APIKeyMiddleware`, otherwise use `BasicAuthMiddleware`."

```golang
func CustomMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // What goes here?
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Middlewares can be composed by calling `ServeHTTP()`. For example:

```golang
func CustomMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Look at the values of r to determine which middleware to use
        BasicAuthMiddleware(next).ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```